# Remove a hyphen from a specific line in a file

Tags: sed, awk

I have a data file that needs to have several uniq identifiers stripped of hyphens.

So I have:

`(Special_Section "data-values")`

and I want to have it replaced with:

`(Special_Section "datavalues")`

I wanted to use a simple sed find/replace, but the data and values are different each time.  Preferably, I'd run this in-place since the file has a lot of other information I want to keep in tact.

Does sed or awk have a way to remove the hyphen from the matched portion only?

Currently I can match with: `sed -i 's/Special_Section "[a-zA-Z0-9]*-[a-zA-Z0-9]*"/&/g *myfiles*`
But I would like to then run `s/-//` on & if it's possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

does this work?

```
sed -i '/(Special_Section ".*-.*")/{s/-//}' yourFile
```

Answer (score 2):

You seems to be using GNU sed, so something like this might work:

```
sed -ri '
  s/(Special_Section [^-]*)-([^)]*)/\1\2/g
  ' <your_filename_glob>
```

Answer (score 1):

Close - scan for the lines and then substitute on those that match:

```
sed -i '/Special_Section "[a-zA-Z0-9]*-[a-zA-Z0-9]*"/s/\( "[a-zA-Z0-9]*\)-\([a-zA-Z0-9]*\)"/\1\2/' *myfiles*
```

You can split that over several lines to avoid the scroll bar in SO:

```
sed -i '/Special_Section "[a-zA-Z0-9]*-[a-zA-Z0-9]*"/{
        s/\( "[a-zA-Z0-9]*\)-\([a-zA-Z0-9]*\)"/\1\2/
        }' *myfiles*
```

---

And on further thoughts, you can also do:

```
sed -i 's/\(Special_Section "[a-zA-Z0-9]*\)-\([a-zA-Z0-9]*"\)/\1\2/' *myfiles*
```

This is more compact.  You can add the `g` qualifier if you need it.  Both solutions use the special `\(...\)` notation to capture parts of the regular expression.